# How to update/delete data from a datagridview?

Tags: postgresql, c#, arcgis-engine

I wanna be able to update/delete data from a datagridview, and when I do that of course the data in my PostgreSQL database should be edited too.
So I've thought about giving the user the ability to select a layer, choose an attribute, choose a logical operator (=, < or >) and then type the criteria he wants for his search.
So for example he could make a search like this one :

> Layer : Activity
>
> Attributes : Id
>
> Logical Operator : =
>
> Criteria : 15

And when he clicks on Search, the result should display on the datagridview
The thing here is, if I want to update a row or a number of rows, how can I be able to do that? Same thing for deleting?
Is it possible to edit data in the datagridview and then I don't know do like an update button and save the changes accordingly but how am I gonna do that ?

## **EDIT**

So now I have this idea : I have two forms :

> **Form 1 : Activity** contains :
>
> > - the datagridview linked to PostgreSQL database (and the DB is linked to ArcCatalog)
> > - a button named Update on which I can click and show the Form2 where I can edit my data (I pass the values from the datagrid view to my textboxes fields in Form2)
> > - a button named Delete on which I can click and delete the IFeature.
>
> **Form 2 : UpdateActivity** contains :
>
> > - the fields of the selected Ifeature, with the values already passed
> > - A Validate button on which I can click and update the data after I finish editing, also the form should close and then I see the updated data in the datagridview in form 1
> >
> > > **P.S** : How can I call the datagridview in the second form?

Here's some code :
On Activity Form:

```
// This is the Update button that pop up the Form2, and it's where I pass the values
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updf = new UpdateForm();

        //Loading data from datagridview to UpdateForm
        updf.txtIdActivity.Text = this.TableAttributaire.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        updf.txtNameActivity.Text = this.TableAttributaire.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        updf.txtAddressActivity.Text = this.TableAttributaire.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        //Update Data
        updf.ShowDialog();

     }
```

On Activity Form:

```
//Clicking on this button should I create another form like I did with the update ?
//Or just delete straight from the datagridview with a messagebox?
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Haven't done it yet?
    }
```

On UpdateActivity Form:

```
//This is the validate click button on which I can click and save and update the data
private void Validate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IFeatureClass pFeatClass;
        IQueryFilter pQF = new QueryFilter();
        // assume pFeatClass is an IFeatureClass object
        // and pQF is a queryfilter that allows to select the features in question.
        IFeatureCursor pCur = pFeatClass.Update(pQF, true); 
        IFeature pFt = pCur.NextFeature();
        pFt.set_Value(indx, pValue); // I don't know what to do here ??
        pCur.UpdateFeature(pFt);  
//But where is the datagridview in all this? How can I call it in this second form and update tha data ?
//Also like I said before I should be able to close this form after I validate and refresh the datagridview in Activity Form
    }
```

**Updating/Deleting from the map**:

> How can I select an object on my map in Activity Form, and display the Update Form accordingly and be able to edit the data?
>   Same thing for deleting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using Esri objects to connect to PostgreSQL.

Each row needs to be updated one row/feature at a time. A row and a feature are identical to a database in that a feature is a row with a geometry registered with the database. In the same way a FeatureClass is a table with a geometry column.

At some stage you have a featureclass, that is an [IFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002qs000000), from that you can create a [cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002vs000000) that which will allow the rows to be updated one at a time:

```
// assume pFeatClass is an IFeatureClass object
// and pQF is a queryfilter that allows to select the features in question.
IFeatureCursor pCur = pFeatClass.update(pQF,true); // true is faster, so long as you don't want to go back
IFeature pFt = pCur.NextFeature();
pFt.set_Value(indx,pValue); // index is the field number, pValue is the value
// now, put it back
pCur.UpdateFeature(pFt);
```

Call `pCur.flush()` when finished with the features to ensure they make it back to the database and occasionally when doing many features (more than 1k) to reduce resources.

To delete features there is `IFeaure.delete();` for a single feature but **ensure that the feature is returned by a non-recycling cursor or the program will crash** i.e. `pFeatClass.update(pQF,false);` but the most efficient way to delete lots of them is using [ITable.DeleteSearchedRows](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000008nz000000), remembering that a featureclass is a special table.

```
ITable pTab = (ITable) pFeatClass;
pTab.DeleteSearchedRows(pQF);
```

When you are finished with your cursors and features destroy the reference using [ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to clear buffers and release database locks.

As for your data grid view I say to [clear it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744882/datagridview-clear) and rebuild it based on the updated features just to be safe.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer @Michael ! But what am I supposed to do in here : pFt.set_Value(indx,pValue); ? Let's say I have two forms, and the second one is where the values of my datagridview are passed, and that's where I can edit, with that being said, when I click on validate this second Form should be closed and the data that I've edited should be saved, also the datagridview on Form1. I've updated my post with further info and some code, please refer and thanks again!

Comment: set_value is used to set the values on the feature, the indx is the index of the field - you can get this by IFeature.Fields.FindField(Name) which will give the index of the field for a name. It sounds like you want to do the update on validate and then call updateform.close() or better yet call it as a dialog, return 1 if the value validates then update the field when the dialog returns 1 and not update for any other value (cancel button). Be aware that the form still exists in memory after it is closed so public variable can still be accessed.